# -bash: cd: No such file or directory error showing But the Folder is Exists

Tags: centos, files, directory

Iam using CentOS7 for my webserver.

I got an error while try to open a directory via SSH.

`ls -l` command shows like this

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 ag007 ag007 38 Mar 17 13:52 Gullane
-rw-r--r-- 1 ag007 ag007  0 Mar 18 03:53 TestFile
drwxr-xr-x 2 ag007 ag007  6 Mar 18 03:58 TestFolder
```

When I enter `cd Gullane` command shows like this

```
-bash: cd: Gullane: No such file or directory
```

PLease help me to access the folder because some important files inside it

Comment: Could there be spaces or other non-printing characters at the end of the name?  Try `cd Gullane*`.

Comment: Hello Kusalananda,

Thank you for your help. Its working now via your help. Now i have updated the name by 

`mv Gullane* Gullane`

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that the directory appeared to have non-visible characters at the end of its name.  Using a shell globbing pattern, `Gullane*`, the user was able to enter the directory, and then also to rename the directory with a more usable name:

```
mv Gullane* Gullane
```

The `*` part of the globbing pattern would match the blank/non-visible characters at the end of the name regardless of what they are.